# Query between Many to Many Models

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

currently I have 2 models with a many to many relationship through a join table.

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :deal_venues, :dependent => :destroy
   has_many :venues, through: :deal_venues
end

class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :deal_venues, :dependent => :destroy
   has_many :deals, through:  :deal_venues
end

class DealVenue < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :deal
   belongs_to :venue
end
```

And here is my schema for these models

```
create_table "deals", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name_of_deal"
    t.string   "type_of_deal"
    t.string   "description"
    t.date     "start_date"
    t.date     "expiry_date"
    t.string   "t_c"
    t.boolean  "pushed"
    t.boolean  "redeemable"
    t.boolean  "multiple_use"
    t.string   "image"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "location"
  end

create_table "venues", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "location"
end

create_table "deal_venues", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "deal_id"
    t.integer  "venue_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

My question is this.
Since my deal_id and venue_id is only in the join table, deal_venues, how do I query between deals and venues since I do not have a ids of each model?
For example, if I am with to query the deals offered within a particular location in venues, how do I do so?
Or perhaps, I wish to query the location where my deal is at.

Sorry for the novice question as I am quite new to rails. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, typically when people say many-to-many relationship in Rails they mean [has-and-belongs-to-many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association). You are using [has-many-through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) relationship. More often than not it is the right way to model many-to-many, just make sure you call things what they are.

Rails (ActiveRecord specifically) will automatically create an `id` column on every table. So you do have `id` on `deals` and `venues`, and you can do things like this:

```
venue_id = <some-id>

venue = Venue.find(venue_id) 

# get all the deals for the venue
deals = venue.deals
```

Comment: I think there might be a slight mistake.
For example, in Deal, it does not have venue_id. I tried deals = Deal.where(venue_id: venue_id) and it does not work.

Also, deals = venue.deals does not work as well.
Apparently, I need to 'code'@venue = Venue.find(venue_id) after which then deals = @venue.deals then it works.
May I know why this is so?

Answer (score 0):

You have `@deal = Deal.find(2)`

Now, you need to

```
@venues = @deal.venues
```

To see SQL query, you need the

```
puts @deal.venues.explain
```

[Rails associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) documentation